# Getting the value number from a combobox to a label

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a booking system and when I finish filling in the requirements of the booking, I have another JFrame that pops up to confirm the name, surname, contact number, quantity and the comments. I managed to get the values from the name,surname and so on into the confirmation JFrame but I do not know how to get the value from the quantity combobox into the label. Any suggestions?

This is the MakeaBooking JFrame :
https://scontent.fmla1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/49938784_2292143167733829_9018705184364167168_n.png?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ht=scontent.fmla1-2.fna&oh=6ab44e33d5bdb7f4924533b140fef155&oe=5C8E9699

This is the ViewaBooking JFrame:
https://scontent.fmla1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/49628762_1986547681466986_2060434174262640640_n.png?_nc_cat=108&_nc_ht=scontent.fmla1-2.fna&oh=558ba8154b676b936a7e114f0e608fbb&oe=5CD1EFD1

Now I just need to get the quantity value from the MakeaBooking into the label field of ViewaBooking.

This is my code so far:
(from 'quantitylabel.setText(MakeaBooking.quantitycb.SelectedItem());' What do I need to change?)

```
 }
public void ConfirmingDetails(){
    namelabel1.setText(MakeaBooking.namefield.getText());
    surnamelabel.setText(MakeaBooking.surnamefield.getText());
    contactlabel.setText(MakeaBooking.contactfield.getText());
    commentslabel.setText(MakeaBooking.commentsfield.getText()); 
    quantitylabel.setText(MakeaBooking.quantitycb.SelectedItem());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the object you added at the selected position with getSelectedItem(). If you want the index of that item in the combo box, use getSelectedIndex() which returns an int.

You need to get the selectedItem from the object and then set it to your label
for example :

```
String itemValue = (String)comboOne.getSelectedItem( );
```